# Input data to mech-dump via STDIN?

Tags: perl

While a:

```
mech-dump foo.html
```

perfectly works, a:

```
FILE="$(cat foo.html)"
echo "$FILE" | mech-dump
Must specify a URL or file to check.  See --help for details.
```

doesn't. How can I put the input to mech-dump via STDIN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. `mech-dump` simply does not support it:

```perl
my $uri = shift or die "Must specify a URL or file to check.  See --help for details.\n";
if ( -e $uri ) {
    require URI::file;
    $uri = URI::file->new_abs( $uri )->as_string;
}
...
my $response = $mech->get( $uri );
```

It simply will try to fetch whatever is given as an argument, and fail if nothing is given.

You'll have to use a temporary file (or process substitution, which amounts to the same thing).